# Using MapKit within the MVC guildines

Tags: swift, mapkit

All, 
I am trying to follow MVC guidelines with my app, so I am removing the code from the View (View Controller). I am trying to get a MapKit displayed with lat/long from Parse. I have it working fine when I enter the lat/long manually.

So I want a computed property (I think) on the tuple. The tuple will hold the lat/long. When the tuple is used, I want to execute the parse query to retrieve the lat/long.

I am a little stuck putting a computed property on a tuple.

Here is my code.

```
var latAndlongTuple = (Double, Double)?
    {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "TableViewData")
        query.includeKey("EventLoc")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for object in objects {
                    var EventLocation = object["EventLoc"] as PFObject!
                    EventLocation.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (EventLocation: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                            let longitude = EventLocation["Latitude"] as NSString
                            let latitude = EventLocation["Longitude"] as NSString
    }

func LocationCoordinate() -> MKCoordinateRegion
{
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latAndlongTuple.0 ,longitude: latAndlongTuple.1)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    return region
}
```

So when the tuple is executed when the function LocationCoordinate is executed, I want the parse code running in the tuple computed property. Then it updates the segments of the tuple with the lat/long.

Any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by :

```
 var latAndlongTuple:(lat : CLLocationDegrees, long : CLLocationDegrees)
        {
        get {
            return (52.606907, -1.104780)
        }

        }
```

and instead of just returning the 2 values, I have used Parse to to get the values and then returned the CLLocationDegree tuple.